# openssl_x509_fingerprint(): cannot get cert from parameter 1

Tags: php

I have the following code that returns error:

> openssl_x509_fingerprint(): cannot get cert from parameter 1

I tried without BEGIN & END CERTIFICATE as well but it doesn't work.

```
$inputCert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'.$cert.'-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
   $thumbprintF = openssl_x509_fingerprint($inputCert, 'sha1', false);
```

cert variable has the value as below

```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```

Answer (score 0):

I need the same thing.
This works for me.

```
$cert = openssl_x509_read($res);
$fingerprint = openssl_x509_fingerprint($cert, 'sha256', false);
var_dump($fingerprint);

string(64) "742056616adf6783747818e8be26f86c613034cc57a53e82ed1cc30a47609fcd"
```

Maybe it can be helpful for somebody else.